# Voltage drop across a diode

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

For the sake of simplicity, the voltage drop across a diode, \$V_d\$ made of silicon is assumed to be \$0.7\mathrm{V}\$ after the input voltage exceeds this voltage; and \$V_d\$ is assumed to stay constant regardless how large the input voltage, \$V_i\$ is after the input voltage exceeds the threshold. In practical, there will be an increase in \$V_d\$, albeit a very small one, as compared to the large increase in \$V_i\$. There is an ideal diode equation:
$$I=I_s\left(e^\frac{qV_i}{kT}-1\right)$$
which relates the current flowing through diode \$I\$ with the input voltage \$V_i\$. So a little increase in \$V_i\$ will result in a large increase in \$I\$, as \$I\$ is an exponential function of \$V_i\$.

I didn't express my question clearly in my previous attempt. Here is my question:

We consider a circuit consists of a diode is connected to a DC power supply. If we were to connect a voltmeter parallel to the diode, and plot the reading of voltmeter(voltage drop across the diode) against the value of the DC input, how will the graph look like? Is there any equation to describe the graph(like the ideal diode equation relating \$I\$ with \$V_i\$)?

Should the equation look something like this? $$V=IR_1+V_t\ln{\left(1+\frac{I}{I_s}\right)}$$ based on an article in Wikipedia under the title Shockley diode equation.

Comment: You are kinda mixing two models. Keep also in mind that \$V_d\$ has no physical equivalent, i.e. it is chosen more or less arbitrarily. Starting from the true diode equation you can't possibly derive \$V_d\$.

Comment: In this case \$V_d = V_i \$

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is that, unlike resistors, capacitors and inductors, diodes are non-linear devices.  You can't use one equation to describe how they work across commonly used voltage / current ranges.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Agree, I didn't realize I had been mixing two models. Is there any equation concerning the voltage drop across the diode? I have been looking up different semiconductor devices textbooks to no avail.

Comment: @st2000 do you mean that we cannot accurately describe diode's behavior for different voltage inputs?

Comment: @VladimirCravero Maybe I didn't express clearly, by \$V_d\$ I meant the voltage drop across the diode(the one we measured when we hooked up a voltmeter across it), not the "on voltage" of the diode.

Comment: You said it yourself that Vd=0.7V. What relationship can there be between Vi and 0.7V? I suppose, depending on Vi it can be either smaller, equal or larger.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Oh, yes it is my mistake. Sorry about that. How about the relationship between voltage drop across the diode and the input voltage? nothing more about the 0.7V

Comment: Isn't the voltage drop also the input voltage, or are we talking about some kind of circuit you're not showing?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I failed to mention anything about the circuit. It is just a simple diode connecting to a DC power supply.

Comment: @Dave Clifford Take a look at this to see if it helps: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106496/why-isnt-there-a-potential-difference-across-a-disconnected-diode?rq=1

Comment: @st2000 you can model nonlinear device with a single equation ... nonlinear equation.

Comment: My suggestion would be to measure the diode drop for a number of different currents and plot up your results.  (say 100 nA to 1 mA)

Answer (score 6):

Let me explain a mathematical origin of the magical number 700 mV. This may help you to understand what's wrong with your question.

Let \$V_T = \frac{kT}{q} \approx 26\,\text{mV}\$ at room temperature. For \$V_d > V_T\$ we can rewrite the diode equation this way:
$$I = I_s \left[\exp\left(\frac{V_d}{V_T}\right) - 1\right]
\approx I_s \exp\left(\frac{V_d}{V_T}\right)
= 1\,\text{A}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{V_d + V_T\log(I_s)}{V_T}\right)$$

A typical value of \$I_s\$ for a silicon p-n diode is around \$1\cdot10^{-12}\,\text{A}\$, so \$\log(I_s) \approx -28\$.

The numerator becomes positive if \$V_d > -V_T\log(I_s) \approx 28\cdot26\,\text{mV} = 728\,\text{mV}\$. Nothing abrupt happens at this point; just a border between negative and positive values of \$x\$ in \$\exp(x)\$, where \$x = \frac{V_d + V_T\log(I_s)}{V_T}\$.

Define \$V_d = 728\,\text{mV}\$ as "the threshold voltage", and the magical number is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Diode is a "current driven" devices. And you should never connect a diode directly across the voltage source without current limiting device in series with the diode. Otherwise the diode will burn. Because the ideal diode act just like a "short circuit" when diode is in forward biased or like a voltage source with constant voltage (0.7V).

As for voltage across the diode versus current we have this 
$$Vd=\frac{kT}{q}*ln(\frac{Id}{Is})$$

And notice that the diode forward voltage have to be increased by only 60mV in order to increase the diode forward current by the factor of 10.
And this is why in most application we assume Vd = 0.7V
http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/The%20Junction%20Diode%20Forward%20Bias%20Equation.pdf
http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/The%20Junction%20Diode%20Curve.pdf