# Test a battery with diode test

Tags: diodes, multimeter, depletion-region

I have just learnt how PN junction work, depletion region etc.
And finally I got what actually multimeter's diode test is measuring.

If there is potential difference between P and N material, and multimeter is showing it, will multimeter show 1.5v voltage drop if I put AA battery instead of a diode?

PS: I'd like to experiment, but I cannot loose my multimeter.

Comment: Go ahead. ..... Experiment. No issue will arise

Comment: *If there is potential difference between P and N material, and multimeter is showing it* It is a common **misconception** to think that you can actually **measure** the potential difference between N and P-type material. **You cannot**, see here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106496/why-isnt-there-a-potential-difference-across-a-disconnected-diode?rq=1  A 1.5 V battery is not a diode or a PN junction, it uses a **chemical reaction** to make that 1.5 V voltage difference.

Comment: Yes you can safely measure that with a multimeter. Look in the manual of the multimeter which voltages it can safely measure. Also make sure you **use it correctly**, i.e. measure voltage in voltage mode and current in current mode, use the right sockets etc.

Comment: @FakeMoustache, yes, I've read that question before. It seems to me, that I understand how it works, and why there is no voltage across unconnected diode. I'm not saying to use voltage meter in my case. Please read carefully the question.