# What is the direction of electric field inside a battery?

Tags: voltage, batteries, field

Outside the battery, in the conductor it is in the direction of conventional current. But what about inside?

Somehow linked: [For p-n junction, at the depletion region which side is at higher potential?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/375712/for-p-n-junction-at-the-depletion-region-which-side-is-at-higher-potential)

But the answer of this question is broad enough to deserve a separate question I guess.

Comment: Why do you think that the direction of the field between the anode and the cathode of the battery would be any different inside versus outside?

Comment: Since magnetism and electricity are related, and magnetic field inside a magnet is from South to North (outside it is North to South), i doubted for any correspondence.